# WPF - Dynamic coloring of TreeViewItem Header

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, header, tree

I'm dynamically creating `TreeViewItems` within a `TreeView`.
On the code behind when a button is clicked I want to make a `header` of a `TreeViewItem`(Which I have access to) to the color red. How can I do that? Binding isn't my strongest side. Is there another way? Anyway I will be glad to understand and study. Example code:

---

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,24,0,0" 
              Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <TreeViewItem Name="Ratata">rere</TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

---

Code Behind:

```
treeView1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
Ratata.Background = Brushes.Red;
Ratata.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Ratata.SetValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

None of these color the header itself to the color red. Any further help?

Comment: How about treeViewItem.Background = Brushes.Red??? :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?put some xaml and c# code you tried.

Comment: treeviewItem.Background doesn't color the header itself to red but draws a red small line before the triangle. Ravuthasamy, There's no much code to show: Let's say you have a TreeViewItem that his header is "Test", I want to make that Test in a red color. Thanks guys !

Comment: try this,             `treeViewItem.SetValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);`

Comment: Tried that, it yet doesn't color the header to the red color, I've added some code that might help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but you have to set the `Header` of the TreeViewItem in order to set the label or else its just an empty item.

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,24,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TreeViewItem Name="Ratata" Header="rere">
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```